# short way to create map from object with counter in java 8

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream

Is there a short way using stream() functionality to get the following functionaity?

```
HashMap<String, Integer> productMap = new HashMap<>();
Integer counter = 0;
for (Product product : products) {
    for (Quality quality :  product.getQualities()) {
        if (quality.evaluate() > Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY) {
            if (productMap.containsKey(quality.getName())) {
                productMap.replace(quality.getName(), counter + 1);
            } else {
                productMap.put(quality.getName(), counter + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need for this conditional behavior, `if(productMap.containsKey(quality.getName())) { productMap.replace(quality.getName(), counter + 1); } else { productMap.put(quality.getName(), counter + 1); }`. A simple `productMap.put(quality.getName(), counter + 1);` does the right thing. Or well, is it really intentional that `counter` is never incremented? Do you actually mean `productMap.put(quality.getName(), ++counter);`?

Comment: It's not much shorter, but yes, you could write this using streams.

Comment: what is the datatype `products` & `product.getQuanlities` ? are these arrays or Lists?

Comment: As @Holger mentioned `counter` is never incremented. That is currently you simply store `1` for each quality. This exact behavior could be implemented in a much shorter way.

Comment: after the counter increment suggestion, something like `products.stream.flatMap.filter.collect(groupingBy(Quality::getName, counting))`

Comment: @Holger: Yes, you are right. I had the incrementation wrong. Thanks a lot for point out where to make my code more efficient! :)

Answer (score -1):

As others have pointed out, `counter` is never incremented. Also, as @Holger mentioned, there is no need to check if `productMap.containsKey()`. If you really want to do the exact same thing you can try:

```java
products.stream()
         .flatMap(product -> product.getQualities().stream())
         .filter(q -> q.evaluate() > Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)
         .map(Quality::getName)
         .forEach(qName -> productMap.put(qName, counter + 1));
```

First, use `flatMap()` to transform the stream of `products` into a stream of `qualities`. Then filter out the ones that evaluate to more than `NEGATIVE_INFINITY`, than transform (`map()`) each one to its name and finally put them in the map.